# Seperate an array into columns , and enter these two in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to separate an array into two different columns.
And make an entry of these 2 separated columns as 2 columns of table as (ID , Name)
For a particular ID i have multiple names.

```
  ($output)
  (
    [0] => 109      ABC
    [1] => 110      CDEEE
    [2] => 109      EFGHI
    [3] => 111      PIJFJJF
  )
```

Above is my array. How do i enter in database.
Please help.
I have tried so far using explode function. `explode(' ,' , $output)`
But i get result different

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question a bit . . . an example of what you'd expect that sample array to look like in your database would be useful.

Comment: `explode()` works on string what you are showing is an array..use `foreach` loop to iterate over this

Comment: I want the sample array to be split in 2 different array. As one of ID(109 , 110, 109, 111) and other array corresponding to the id their names as Name(ABC , CDEEE , EFGHI,  PIJFJJF) .

Comment: @Rinku can u plz confirm that thr is a lot of space in between `109      ABC`

Comment: Actually the $output array in example above is a result of an sql query derived from joining different tables. When i print the array as print_r($output) yes i get the output as 109 with space ABC.

Comment: @Rinku PhpMyCoder has your answer....he had it ages ago...

Answer (score 5):

The SQL pattern which you are looking for is a one-to-many relationship. It can map multiple names to one id using one table:

```
Names
---------
Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL (Primary Key)
Id   INT NOT NULL (Index)
```

You can create this table with:

```
CREATE TABLE Names(
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Id   INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`Name`),
    INDEX `Id_idx` (`Id`)
);
```

Then you can insert each name for each id into the db using:

```
INSERT INTO Names (Name, Id) VALUES('ABC', 109);
```

Using [PDO prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you can do:

```
$stmt = $dhb->prepare('INSERT INTO Names (Name, Id) VALUES(:name, :id)');

foreach($names as $nameStr) {
    list($id, $name) = explode(' ', $nameStr); // split "109 ABC" into id: 109 and name: ABC
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':id' => $id,
        ':name' => $name
    ));

}
```

And to retrieve all of the names for an index you can use this PDO query:

```
$id = 123;
$names = array();

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE Id = :id');
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));

while(($newName = $stmt->fetchColumn(0)) !== false) {
    $names[] = $newName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach loop with your array like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (ID,Name) VALUES";
$i = 0;
$my_id = "your id";
$my_cnt = count($my_array);
foreach($my_array as $name) {
      $exploded = explode(' ',$name);
      $sql .= "($exploded[0],$exploded[1])";
      if($i++ < $my_cnt) 
         $sql .= " , ";
}
echo $sql;
```

then execute the query $sql

Comment: +1 Might want to add a note about sanitization of the input though.

Comment: You have multiple errors in this code...one $my_id, is meaningless...two, you append VALUES to VALUES, multiple times...and theres more

Comment: @KyleK my_id will be the id the he want to add,and what is values appending to values .Simply echo that query you will see that how much correct it is

Comment: well you have VALUES at the end of $sql at the top, meaning that if you then do a concatenation onto it, you'll end up with INSERT INTO my_table(ID,Name) VALUES VALUES (myid, $name),VALUE($id, $name) etc

Comment: Yes exactly i want to enter the values as two different columns in the database. But how do i derive the seperated columns from the array($output) .

Comment: See my edit....i edited...thnnks @KyleK .I didnt see that...by mistake it was typed

Comment: I didnt seen his edited array...Sorry for that...I will edit my ans as well

Comment: Almost, but he seeems to have multiple spaces between his columns, so it will likely be something like $exploded = explode("   ",$name);  depending on the length between...you have no whitespace

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31906/discussion-between-gautam3164-and-kylek)

Comment: Im talking about the space between explode("",$name);  you had "" then you edited to  " " , which is right.....at first you didnt have space between....now you do

Comment: oh that one..??it happens while typing @KyleK